# When I type something in the searchview it only shows the first item (FIREBASE)

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

When I type something in the searchview it only shows the first item.

I created a simple database containing:
A, B AND C. But when I type for example B in my searchview it only shows item A.
And when I delete my text, A, B and C shows in my listview, and if I type D, nothing is showing in my listview (like it should).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Model Class:

```
public class Verktoy {
String verktøynavn;
String verktøytype;
String verktøystatus;
String utlånttil;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return verktøynavn;
}

public Verktoy() {

}

public Verktoy(String verktøynavn, String verktøytype, String verktøystatus, String utlånttil) {
    this.verktøynavn = verktøynavn;
    this.verktøytype = verktøytype;
    this.verktøystatus = verktøystatus;
    this.utlånttil = utlånttil;
}

public String getVerktøynavn() {
    return verktøynavn;
}

public String getVerktøytype() {
    return verktøytype;
}

public String getVerktøystatus() {
    return verktøystatus;
}

public String getUtlånttil() {
    return utlånttil;
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class listVerktoy extends ArrayAdapter<Verktoy> {

private Activity context;
private List<Verktoy> listverktoy;



public listVerktoy(Activity context, List<Verktoy> listverktoy){
    super (context, R.layout.list_verktoyalt, listverktoy);
    this.context = context;
    this.listverktoy = listverktoy;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();



    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_verktoyalt, null, true);

    TextView tvverktøynavnlist = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøynavnlist);
    TextView tvverktøytypelist = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøytypelist);
    TextView tvverktøystatuslist = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvverktøystatuslist);
    TextView tvutlånttil = (TextView)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvutlånttil);


    Verktoy verktoy = listverktoy.get(position);

    tvverktøynavnlist.setText(verktoy.getVerktøynavn());
    tvverktøytypelist.setText(verktoy.getVerktøytype());
    tvverktøystatuslist.setText(verktoy.getVerktøystatus());
    tvutlånttil.setText(verktoy.getUtlånttil());

    return listViewItem;
```

MainActivty:

```
public class Verktoyliste extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databaseVerktøy;


Button btnleggtilverktøy;
ListView lvverktøylistealt;
Button button3;
SearchView schverktøy;





List<Verktoy> listverktoy;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verktoyliste);

    databaseVerktøy = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Verktøy");





    lvverktøylistealt = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvverktøylistealt);



    schverktøy = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.schverktøy);





    btnleggtilverktøy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnleggtilverktøy);

    listverktoy = new ArrayList<>();



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseVerktøy.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {



        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {




            listverktoy.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot verktoySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                Verktoy verktoy = verktoySnapshot.getValue(Verktoy.class);

                listverktoy.add(verktoy);

                final listVerktoy adapter = new listVerktoy(Verktoyliste.this, listverktoy);
                lvverktøylistealt.setAdapter(adapter);

                schverktøy.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                        databaseVerktøy.orderByChild("verktøynavn").equalTo(query);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        databaseVerktøy.orderByChild("verktøynavn").equalTo(newText);

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        return true;
                    }
                });


            }






        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1. way to much code 2. firebase has nothing to do with this 3. your real problem is filtering results, search for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute this code:

```
databaseVerktøy.orderByChild("verktøynavn").equalTo(newText);
```

It returns a new query, it does **not** modify the existing one. So every time you want to filter on a new condition, you will need to:

1. Create a new query based on the new filter

   ```
   Query query = databaseVerktøy.orderByChild("verktøynavn").equalTo(newText);
   ```
2. Attach a listener to this new query.
3. Create a new adapter with the results of this new query, or update the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I manage to search in my listview now. But when I click on the searched item the last added item shows up in my alertdialog, not the searched item. What is wrong here?

Comment: Actually it is not my last added item, it is always the item at the top of the listview (alphabetical).

Comment: I manage to work this out too :) Thank you for your help @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Here we go again, how can I reset my searchview with the X on the right side? So if I press the X all my items will show in my listview. No it's just appearing blank.